# Editing text at a specific point on every line of a text file

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file containing a list of nine-digit numbers like this:

```
550411876
550425175
550426504
```

And a second text file that contains a single line like this:

```
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|ABxxxxxxxxx|AC|CH|BIN|
```

I need to make a text file that contains many occurrences of the line from the second file, but with the `xxxxxxxxx` replaced with the number from the first file (the `xxxxxxxxx` is literally in the file, it's not just an example). In this case the result would be:

```
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550411876|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550425175|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550426504|AC|CH|BIN|
```

How do I do this in Linux?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the numbers are in the file `numbers` and that the template file that you'd like to use is `file`:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR { n[++i] = $0; next } { for (i in n) { $3 = substr($3,1,2) n[i]; print } }' numbers file
```

This would first read the numbers into the array `n`, and then, for the template file, use the first two characters from the third `|`-delimited field, concatenate that with the numbers from the `n` array and print the result once for each number.

The `-F'|' -v OFS='|'` options makes sure that we both read and write the data as `|`-delimited.

Then just redirect the output of this into a new file.

This does not rely on the template to contain `xxxxxxxxx`.

Testing it:

```
$ cat file
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB something something|AC|CH|BIN|

$ awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' 'NR==FNR { n[++i] = $0; next } { for (i in n) { $3 = substr($3,1,2) n[i]; print } }' numbers file
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550425175|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550426504|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550411876|AC|CH|BIN|
```

---

A `bash`-only approach (no external utilities) which uses the nine `x`-es:

```
template=$(<file)
while read number; do
    printf '%s\n' "${template//xxxxxxxxx/$number}"
done <numbers
```

Answer (score 5):

Apparently  your template has only one line...

If this is true we can

```
for a in $(< list)
do
    printf "09Y20171031    13415520171031   134155AP|AO|AB%s|AC|CH|BIN|\n" $a
done
```

Comment: why `for a in $(< list)` instead of `while read a; ...; done < list` ?

Answer (score 3):

with `list` being number list and `tmpl` being template file

```
for y in $(< list )
do
   sed -r -s s/[x]{9}/$y/ < tmpl
done
```

give

```
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550411876|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550425175|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550426504|AC|CH|BIN|
```

where

- `for y in $(< list )` read each line and put value into variable `y`
- `sed -r` use gnu extension
- `-e s/[x]{9}/../` replace 9 occurence of character x ...
- `../$y/` ... by content of var y

you will have to redirect for loop to a file

```
done > my_file
```

Comment: This works but will use _n_ `sed` invocations where `n=$(wc -l <list)` so for a file with one million lines you're calling `sed` one million times.

Answer (score 3):

Another **awk** approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ a[++c]=$1; next }
     { for(i in a) { r=$0; sub(/x{9}/,a[i],r); print r } }' file1 file2
```

- `a[++c]=$1` - capturing numbers from the `file1` into array `a`
- `for(i in a)` - iterating through *nine-digit numbers*
- `sub(/x{9}/,a[i],r)` - substitute the crucial sequence `xxxxxxxxx` with *next* number contained in `a[i]`

---

The output:

```
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550411876|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550425175|AC|CH|BIN|
09Y20171031    13415520171031    134155AP|AO|AB550426504|AC|CH|BIN|
```

Comment: I would have done it the other way around : `awk 'NR==1{split($0,z,/x{9}/);next}{printf ("%s%s%s\n", z[1], $0, z[2])}' file2 file1`

Comment: @don_crissti, good trick, you may post it as an answer with explanations to present an alternative way for the community

Comment: There are already too many answers. If you like it then you may include it in your answer and I'll delete my comment here.

Comment: @don_crissti, I don't want to assume your original idea. Post it  with explanations and you'll get my upvote

Answer (score 1):

Perl can't be missing here.

```
p=$(< pat) perl -nlE'$l = $ENV{p}; $n=$_; $l =~ s/x{9}/$n/; say $l if /./' nums
```

`pat` is the pattern file name

`p` is an environment variable carrying the pattern

`n` is a Perl variable containing the number in each iteration

`l` contains line (first the pattern for each line, then after the substitution the actual line to print)

`nums` is the numbers file name